# Change the format of a date in a Web Service

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, glassfish

i have table "`news`", that has a column called `dateNews` (type date )

in `PostgreSQL` the date has the following format : `2014-04-16`

but in my jpa web service the format is the following : "`2014-04-16T00:00:00+03:00`"

how can i format my date to the following format : `dd/mm/yyyy`

and where should i do it is it in my `PostgreSQL` database or in my jpa web service ?

Answer (score 1):

This conversion should be done in the service, not at the database level. Make sure your field is type java.sql.Date and use java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Main reasons to add this at the service level are extensibility and maintainability. You want a single point where you do all this formatting, probably based on user preferences. You don't want to add this to every query you are doing, and maintaining the format throughout those queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to output a formated string (`text`):

```
SELECT to_char(datenews, 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM news;
```